# Events - Publish & Subscribe

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Lets say I have a class which has a static event in it. This event is subscribe by three or more different classes. [Lets say 4]

Now when something noteworthy happen the event in class got raised.

As 4 different classes subscribe to the event, the corresponding handler in them execute their respective code.

Now if i don't want the handler code of my class no 3 & 4 to execute. What should i need to do?

Please help.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you don't want those handlers to execute, why did they subscribe? How do you know which handlers not to execute? Your question is very unclear at the moment.

Comment: If you made the event public you can reuse it in every other class

Comment: This isn't a good use for event pattern. You are better off creating a subscription system where the subscriber registers a delegate (almost like an event), but the publisher can go through the subscribers one-by-one and decide to call that delegate. This is a little different than multi-cast delegates in that you don't combine them into one like an event does.

Comment: That is what i want to know.. How can i decide which handler to call or not? @RonBeyer Can you please drop some light on subscription pattern you just mentioned above? i want to know how to implement this pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under what conditions do you want your handlers to fire?

You can have the following pattern which will provide a mechanism to prevent the handlers firing based on a unique identifier.

In this example, I create some simple event args which the event will use to tell the handler a unique identifier (Guid):

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs { public Guid Identifier { get; set; } }
```

Then, create a simple class to raise the event:

```
public class EventGenerator
{
    public EventHandler<MyEventArgs> TheEvent;

    public void RaiseEvent(Guid identifier)
    {
        if (TheEvent != null) 
            TheEvent(this, new MyEventArgs(){Identifier = identifier});
    }
}
```

Finally, you can have a class (any number of these) which will all subscribe to the event but will only run it when the event args supplies a different identifier:

```
public class TheClass
{
    private readonly Guid _identifier;
    private EventGenerator _eventGenerator;

    // The constructor is given the event generator class instance
    public TheClass(EventGenerator evGen)
    {
        // create a unique identifier for the class
        _identifier = Guid.NewGuid();

        // subscribe to the event
        _eventGenerator = evGen;
        _eventGenerator.TheEvent += TheEvent;
    }

    private void TheEvent(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
    {
        // when the event fires, check the Guid and if it isn't a match, don't continue ...
        if (e.Identifier == _identifier) return;

        // rest of the handler goes here ...
    }
}
```

This is just an example, however - you may need something different which might be achievable by simply unsubscribing to the event at choice times.  It depends on the answer to my initial question.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out on this.